# how to declare var keyword for variable globally in mvc controller

Tags: model-view-controller, global, var

I want to declare **var** keyword in globally for the variable in mvc controller
Because I am using that variable at multiple times thats why I want to use that variable as a globally.
But I dont know that how **var** is been done by globally because **var** is different type as per **string, int, decimal** to place in globally.

For more clear lets see the code

```
var query = new List<T>();
if (model.CategoryId == -1)
{
   query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
}
else
{
   query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true && w.CategoryId == model.CategoryId).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
}
var dataList = (from x in query
    select new
    {
    })
```

Now, here **query** variable is used many times in code. Now, I want to declare globally this query variable. This is the latest code that I tried. In this error is showing by giving red line in code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your "Global" definition isn't clear. Do you want to use "query" instance for one Class or want to use for all class that generated by one class.

Secondly if you want to use as Global, you should define your global variable like this

```
List<dynamic> query=new List<dynamic>();
```

of course this kind of approach is not healthy way (dynamic using with c#)

By the way, you can't use "var" keyword in out of functions. You have to use certain type of variable destination in class level.

**Define Variable in Class Level**

In the given piece of code, I try to define global variable at class level.

```
public class MyTestClass
{
 List<dynamic> query=new List<dynamic>(); 

public MyTestClass()
{
}

public void generateQuery()
{

if (model.CategoryId == -1)
{
query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
}
else
{
   query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true && w.CategoryId == model.CategoryId).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
}
var dataList = (from x in query
    select new
    {
    })

}
}
}
```

Let's let try to cover another approach.

**Use The Generated Class's Variable As Global Variable**

At this time you can define your global variable in  ancestor class

```
public class MyAncestorClass
{

    List<dynamic> query=query=new List<dynamic>(); 

}


public class MyChildClass:MyAncestorClass
{

 public void generateQuery()
    {

    if (model.CategoryId == -1)
    {
    query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
       query = _Db.Purchase.Where(w => w.IsIncludeIntoStock == true && w.CategoryId == model.CategoryId).ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.ManufacturerId, x.CategoryId, x.Weight, x.WeightTypeId }).ToList();
    }
    var dataList = (from x in query
        select new
        {
        })

    }
    }

}
```